# What's the conditional distribution of X given X = Y

Tags: conditional-probability

I'm in a setting in which X and Y are both $Beta(0.5, 0.5)$ and indipendent, that is

$$f(x, y) = \frac{1}{\pi^2\sqrt{x(1-x)y(1-y)}}$$

What is the conditional distribution of X given Y = X? Normally i would substitute x to y in the density function and i would find a normalization constant. But in this case we would have

$$f(x) \propto \frac{1}{x(1-x)}$$

which is not integrable. But it feels strange to me that a well defined distribution on a bidimensional set, becomes undefined when restricted to a subspace of the original domain. Am I doing something wrong? There actually exist the pdf of this conditional distribution?

Comment: The usual thing is to ask about the distribution of $X$ given $g(x,y)=a$, whose cdf is defined as $$F(x) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}P[X<x:|g(x,y)-a|<\epsilon]$$ But beware that conditioning on $x-y=0$ may give different results from conditioning on $x^2-y^2=0$.

Comment: Hint (for intuition and a solution): re-express the variables as $x=\sin\theta$ and $y=\sin\phi.$  The apparent problem will disappear *provided you do the calculation correctly.*  After verifying that, see whether you can translate this result into the original variables.